# Can I pass DC 36V 100A through a terminal block that is rated for DC 300V 30A?

Tags: power-supply, connector, terminal, terminal-block

In the system that I am designing, the peak current that the system requires is 80A at 36V DC. The terminal blocks that are available on the market are rated for 300V 30A. I want to know if the terminal rating is calculated based on the power that it can handle or only the current it can handle irrespective of the voltage rating.

Comment: The Joule effect depends solely on intensity (amperes)…

Comment: the voltage limit is based on the plastic, the current limit is based on the metal.

Comment: Probably not. How short in time is your peak?

Comment: What's your RMS current? That's relevant to heating of conductors in series, like the wiring and the terminal block.

Comment: if the 2.5x current only happens for 1% of the time and the rest it's below max, it should be ok.

Comment: You wouldn’t use the 300V in a power calculation, you would use the voltage drop across the terminal block, which would be a lot lower.

Comment: Make one: flattened copper pipe mounted on insulators.

Comment: If the load can be fused with a 30A fuse (even a slo-blo), then the terminal block is probably okay.

Comment: Once you find a suitable terminal block, remember to observe the torque specification also. 80A bolt connections need to be pretty tight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your second premise is correct as with any connectors, it can handle only the maximum ratings in each respect alone.

So no going over the current spec because the voltage is lower.

Study the datasheet carefully, because sometimes there are derating curves, so that for the maximum rated voltage the maximum current is lower or AC/DC differences.

Some parts are also able to handle a pulsed current, so a brief overload may be okay. But again this has to be specified. (it likely isn't so reaching out to the manufacturer is often helpful)

Answer (score 11):

The application using a terminal block should keep within **all** of the block ratings. That is, it should have a lower Voltage, lower Current and lower Power.

Now there may be some wriggle room in the ratings themselves. The 30 A current rating would be for continuous current. If the duration of an intermittent higher current is much less than the thermal time constant of the terminals, so the temperature of the terminals changes little during the pulse, then there may be a case for asking the manufacturer if the block has a pulse rating. The RMS of the pulsey current waveform would have to stay below 30 A to keep long term control of temperature.

That's the physics of the situation, and applicable if you're doing a one-off hobby build in a non-critical place. If insurance could be involved, then using a connector at way over specification is guaranteed to get your claim turned down, even it's not directly involved with whatever went wrong.